# i am unable to print the linked list

Tags: c, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{  
    struct node
    {   
         int data;
         struct node *next;
    };

    struct node *first=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *second=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *third=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    scanf("%d %d %d",&(first->data),&(second->data),&(third->data));
    first->next=second;
    second->next=third;
    third->next=NULL;
    struct node *t=(struct node *)first;
    f(t);
 }

f(struct node *a)
{
    while(a!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",a->data);
        a= a->next;
    }
}
```

the code above is giving a warning and an error "struct node declared inside parameter list" and "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

kindly help me making the code run and solving error.

Comment: *Where* is the structure defined? It will only be defined in that scope.

Comment: what do you mean..?

Comment: Perhaps you should take some time to learn about *scopes*? Any beginners book or tutorial or course should have mentioned it, and that things defined in one scope is only available in that (and *nested*) scopes.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues.

- your functions don't have a return type
- your `struct node` is declared only in the scope of `main`.
- you use the `f` function before it has been declared.
- last but not least: the formatting of your code is horrible. Formatting isn't important for the compiler, but only for the human reader including you

This is what your program should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node               // structure declared at global scope
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

void f(struct node *a);   // declare function

int main()                // function has now return type int
{
  struct node *first = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  struct node *second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  struct node *third = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  scanf("%d %d %d", &(first->data), &(second->data), &(third->data));
  first->next = second;
  second->next = third;
  third->next = NULL;
  struct node *t = (struct node *)first;
  f(t);
}

void f(struct node *a)   // function has now return type void
{
  while (a != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d", a->data);
    a = a->next;
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: this program just compiles correctly without warnings, but I didn't check if it actually makes sense.

Comment: The definition of the `f` function actually **is** outside the `main` function. And _that_ is why `f` doesn't see the `struct node` declaration.

Comment: @CiaPan oh, you're right. Edited. That's why the last point of my list is important ;-)

Comment: I agree. I was going to answer this question too, but you were faster. And my answer was essentialy same as yours, except I put the last point at the top of the list. Programs are for computers, but the source code is for humans. So it should always be as readable as possible.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it compiled and made a sense too ;-) it is a program to print a linkedlist recursively.

Comment: @ShivamSingh yes, it seems to be correct, but there is no recursion though.

Comment: i have a question why do we need to declare function and struct outside main body...

Comment: what if we write it as  void f(struct node *a)   {if (a){ printf("%d",a->data); f(a->next) will it be recursive

Comment: @ShivamSingh 1. nested functions are not standard C, 2. if the struct is declaire inside the `main` function, it is only visible from inside the `main` function, and that is clearly not what you need here.

Comment: @ShivamSingh please ask another question. This is a different matter. Don't put code in comments, it's hardly readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* ===== Define structure outside function ===== */
/*
    Use `typedef` to rename the data type.
    `node_t` is equal with `struct node_t`, and
    `node` is equal with `struct node_t *`.
 */
typedef struct node_t
{
    int data;
    struct node_t *next;
} node_t, *node;

/*  Define link list
 */
typedef struct list_t
{
    node head;
    node rear;
    int size;
} list_t, *list;

list list_create()
{
    list l = NULL;

    if ((l = malloc(sizeof(list_t))) == NULL)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    memset(l, 0, sizeof(list_t));

    return l;
}

int list_destroy(list *pl)
{
    node cur;
    node prev;

    if (pl == NULL || *pl == NULL)
        return -1;

    cur = (*pl)->head;
    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
        free(prev);
    }

    free(*pl);
    *pl = NULL;

    return 0;
}

int list_push(list l, int data)
{
    node n;

    if (l == NULL)
        return -1;

    if ((n = malloc(sizeof(node_t))) == NULL)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }

    n->data = data;
    n->next = NULL;

    if (l->head == NULL)
    {
        l->head = n;
    }
    else
    {
        l->rear->next = n;
    }

    l->rear = n;
    l->size++;

    return 0;
}

int list_pop(list l, int *pdata)
{
    if (l == NULL || l->head == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    *pdata = l->head->data;
    if (l->head == l->rear)
    {
        l->rear = NULL;
    }
    l->head = l->head->next;

    l->size--;

    return 0;
}

void list_foreach(list l, void (*func)(int data, void *arg), void *arg)
{
    node cur = l->head;

    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        func(cur->data, arg);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}


static void print_node(int data, void *arg)
{
    printf("%d\n", data);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int d;
    list l;

    l = list_create();

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &d);
        getchar();
        list_push(l, d);
    }

    list_foreach(l, print_node, NULL);

    printf("Pop: [status %d], ", list_pop(l, &d));
    printf("[value %d]\n", d);

    printf("Pop: [status %d], ", list_pop(l, &d));
    printf("[value %d]\n", d);

    list_foreach(l, print_node, NULL);

    list_destroy(&l);

    return 0;

}
```